# SAS - Macro - Column names with spaces/punctuation marks troublesome when sorting alphabetically

Tags: sorting, sas, sas-macro

I have a big table in SAS where columns represent all the countries in the world. I have created it through long-to-wide transpose and I am representing a value for each ID in each respective country - see the code below:

```
proc transpose data=basic_summarised out=cntrs_transposed (drop=_name_ _label_);
    by ID code;
    id country;
    var value;
run;
```

My goal now is to re-arrange the columns so that the country columns appear in an output alphabetically. To achieve this, I run a macro:

```
%macro reorder_vars(Dataset);
proc sql noprint;
select compress(name,,'kn') into : dsn separated by " "
from dictionary.columns
where libname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,1,.))" and memname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,2,.))"
order by name
;
quit;
 
data %scan(&dataset,2,.);
retain ID code &dsn;
set &Dataset;
run;
%mend;
 
%reorder_vars(work.cntrs_transposed);
```

This works but only on countries with one-word names, those with punctuation marks or spaces end up at the very end of the variable list (examples of those countries are United States, Congo (Republic), etc.). I tried changing the compress modifiers to 'ps', thinking that it would get rid of punctuation and spaces but the table remains unchanged.

I am not sure if there is anything else here I could do to achieve the desired result?

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the name for the United States column in the data set? Is it 'United States'n or is it United_States?

The same notation needs to be used for the RETAIN statement.

NLITERAL can be used if the name has spaces.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into : dsn separated by " "
from dictionary.columns
where libname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,1,.))" and memname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,2,.))"
order by name
;
quit;
```

Comment: The country names have spaces in between them, not underscores. Thank you for suggesting using nliteral, it did solve my problem and now all of them are in an order I was expecting!

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you just put the list of names into the macro variable in the order you want them to appear?  At a minimum use the NLITERLA() function to make sure the list of names is valid SAS syntax and use UPCASE() function so United States will sort before USA.

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :namelist separated by " "
 from dictionary.columns
  where libname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,1,.))"
    and memname="%upcase(%scan(&dataset,2,.))"
  order by upcase(name)
;
quit;
 
data %scan(&dataset,2,.);
  retain ID code &namelist;
  set &Dataset;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to use the nliteral() function, I wasn't aware of its existence. I have now run the macro again with the function as suggested and the columns come out as I would expect. Thanks again!